# Download a generated file with Python

Tags: python, svg

I'm using Batik to generate a png file from a svg file using Python.

I would like to download directly the generated file into the user's personal disk.

Here's my Python script :

```
#!C:\Python27\python.exe -u

import os
import cgi
import urllib
print "Content-type: application/image/png\n\n" 
print "Content-Disposition: attachment, filename=pythonchart.png\n\n"

arg = cgi.FieldStorage()
file = open('C:\wamp\www\myproj\pythonchart.svg', 'w+')
file.write(arg['svgdata'].value)
file.close()
os.system('java -jar "C:\Program Files\\batik-1.7\\batik-rasterizer.jar" "C:\wamp\\www\\metrics1\\pythonchart.svg"')
os.remove('C:\wamp\www\myproj\pythonchart.svg')
```

This results in a download dialog of this python script, I'm aware it's because of the header(content-type), but how can I add the header to that png image and download it please ?

Comment: I figure you are using this in a web environment, so your script shall be run as a CGI script?

Comment: You should have stated that in the question and title to avoid confusion ;-)  Concerning your issue:  Your script currently is not _run_ by the web server as a CGI script.  That's not a programming question and better suited for Stackoverflow's sister forum "Server Fault".  Let's migrate it there.

Comment: alright thanks hopefully someone will help me there